# Java get back user input as total

Tags: java

My goal is the get number of guests associated with the name. However that's not what I am getting.Can you please suggest an alternative solution to this?

```
public class GuestAdult {

    public String guestFname;
    public int aNum;

    public static ArrayList<String>adGuestName= new ArrayList<String>(); 
    public static ArrayList<Integer>adGuestNum= new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

    public static Scanner userInput= new Scanner(System.in);

    public void createAdultList(){
        System.out.println("Enter family name: ");
        guestFname=userInput.next();

        System.out.println("Enter adult guest number: ");
        aNum=userInput.nextInt();

        adGuestName.add(guestFname);
        adGuestNum.add(aNum);


    }

    public void totalAdultGuests(){
        System.out.println("The number of total adults is " + adGuestNum.size());
    }

}
```

Current Output

> Enter family name:
>   R
>   Enter adult guest number:
>   2
>   Add another guest: Y/N
>   N
>   The number of total adults is 1 <**How can I see 2 here?**>
>   END

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? Supposedly you're only calling `createAdultList` (consider renaming your methods and fields) once and so the size of the list is one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ArrayList` is, like the name, a list of items - in your case, a list of `Integer`s. When you take the user's input for the number of guests, you are taking a single `Integer` with the value `2`, then adding it as the first number in `adGuestNum`, which is a *list* of numbers. Since calling `size()` on an `ArrayList` just gives you the number of *elements in the list*, and you only added one element (even though that element is `2`, `2` is just one number regardless of its value), `size()` is going to return `1`.

Since it looks like you're going to want to add multiple families and loop over some of your code multiple times, you probably want to be adding up the contents of the list, instead of just looking at how many numbers are in the list. For this, you'll need to loop over the list and look at each number, adding it to a counter as you go:

```
public void totalAdultGuests(){
    int totalGuests = 0;
    for(Integer guests : adGuestNum) {
        totalGuests += guests;
    }
    System.out.println("The number of total adults is " + totalGuests);
}
```

This looks at each number in `adGuestNum` and adds it to the counter `totalGuests`. Once it's done, it prints out the `totalGuests` instead of just the number of groups in `adGuestNum`.